Why vacuum does not have absolute zero temperature?
Extrapolation of P vs. T graph gives absolute zero or 0K. Does that mean that if we achieve perfect vacuum, we can have absolute zero? If not why? Let us assume a perfect vacuumn space where there are no stars and planetary bodies near by and its pitch dark. Then will the temperature be anywhere near to 0K?

Does this answer your question? Temperature in space

The linked question answers my doubt on temperature of space. But it does not seem to answer the main part of my doubt which is written in bold text. I request the moderators to reopen this question.
